# Draw a pretty cross-indicator on this screen magnifier?

Tags: .net, vb.net, drawing, gdi+, paint

I would like to draw a pretty 'indicator' like a cross or something else to know exactly where is ponting the mouse in a screen magnifier, drawing a cross-indicator os the mousecursor around the pixel.

Unafortunally my GDI+ knowledges are not good.

This is how it looks the magnifier window:

[image]

And I would like to draw something like a indicator, the current mousecursor or a cross-indicator like this ( but this is too ugly and has any pixel precission 'cause I've used MsPaint )

[image]

Someone could help me to do this?

This is how I'm drawing the Image:

```
''' <summary>
''' Repaints the Magnifier.
''' </summary>
Private Sub Repaint()

    ' Region Length.
    Dim lengthX As Single = Me.Width * ZoomFactor
    Dim lengthY As Single = (Me.Height - ZoomFactor_KryptonTrackBar.Bounds.Height) * ZoomFactor

    ' Center Image Around The Mouse.
    Dim offsetX As Single = (Me.Width * ZoomFactor) \ 2
    Dim offsetY As Single = (Me.Height * ZoomFactor) \ 2

    ' Actual Area To Blit To.
    Dim blitAreaX As Integer = Me.Width
    Dim blitAreaY As Integer = Me.Height - ZoomFactor_KryptonTrackBar.Bounds.Height

    bmp = New Bitmap(CInt(blitAreaX), CInt(blitAreaY))
    g1 = ZoomFactor_PictureBox.CreateGraphics
    g2 = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)

    ' Set the image quality.
    g1.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.None
    g1.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighSpeed
    g1.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighSpeed
    g1.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor

    g2.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.None
    g2.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighSpeed
    g2.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighSpeed
    g2.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor

    ' Devicecontext (DC) of the Desktop and the Graphics object.
    Dim hWndWindow As IntPtr = GetDesktopWindow()
    Dim hdcWindow As IntPtr = GetDC(hWndWindow)
    Dim hdcGraphics As IntPtr = g2.GetHdc()

    ' BitBlt the Screen (Captures Transparent Windows & Prevents Mirror Effect)
    BitBlt(hdcGraphics.ToInt32, 0, 0, blitAreaX, blitAreaY,
           hdcWindow.ToInt32, MousePosition.X - offsetX, MousePosition.Y - offsetY,
           TernaryRasterOperations.SRCCOPY Or
           TernaryRasterOperations.CAPTUREBLT Or
           TernaryRasterOperations.NOMIRRORBITMAP)

    ' Free Memory
    ReleaseDC(hWndWindow, hdcWindow)
    g2.ReleaseHdc(hdcGraphics)

    ' Paint
    g1.DrawImage(bmp, New Rectangle(0, 0, blitAreaX, blitAreaY), 0, 0, lengthX, lengthY, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)

    ' Set Magnifier position.
    ' Do this after painting to reduce blinking effects.
    SetMangifierPosition()

End Sub
```

> Update

I've did a modification to draw the default Cross mouse cursor but it's not correctly alligned, I don't know why is happening because I've divided by half the control size where the image is drawn to center the cursor on the bitmap:

NOTE: But if I zoom at 100% then I can notice that the cursor stills unalligned but it is ponting to the right pixel, I don't understand this.

```
...
    ' Paint
    g1.DrawImage(bmp, New Rectangle(0, 0, blitAreaX, blitAreaY), 0, 0, lengthX, lengthY, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
...

    ' And paint the mouse cursor
    Cursors.Cross.Draw(g1, New Rectangle(ZoomFactor_PictureBox.Width \ 2, ZoomFactor_PictureBox.Height \ 2, 0, 0))
```

[image]

> UPDATE 2

Solved:

[image]

```
    ' Paint
    g1.DrawImage(bmp, New Rectangle(0, 0, blitAreaX, blitAreaY), 0, 0, lengthX, lengthY, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)

    ' Set the cursor Rectangle.
    Dim CursorRect As New Rectangle With
    {
     .Size = New Size(0, 0),
     .Location = New Point((ZoomFactor_PictureBox.Width \ 2) - Cursors.Cross.Size.Width \ 2,
                           (ZoomFactor_PictureBox.Height \ 2) - Cursors.Cross.Size.Height \ 2 - 10)
    }

    ' Paint the mouse cursor
    Cursors.Cross.Draw(g1, CursorRect)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either store the png of the cross hairs with a transparent background and `DrawImage` over the top of what you have:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawimage(v=vs.110).aspx

Or manually draw `g1.DrawLine` four times:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawline(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I've followed your suggestion but I still have a problem with the cursor, please see my update